# Help me to symbolicate crash

Tags: iphone, ios4, crash

My Friend has got a application crash in his iphone and he has sent only a Preferences-2011-06-20-202724.plist file.

I am trying to symbolicate the crash using that plist file but no luck found so far.

Is it possible to symbolicate the crash using that plist file alone? if so ...how can i proceed?

Thanks a lot

Note : My friend is far away from myself and i cant get his device for testing it myself. so he sent plist file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the device to the mac and in xcode you can see crash log by selecting device in organizer. There are also some tools available for the process but you need to search on google for them.

Comment: hi.. My friend is far away from myself and i cant get his device for testing it myself. so he sent plist file

Comment: @barbgal you need dyslm file to symbolicate crash report.